# running bash over ssh in one-liner command wierd tty

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm running the following command for an automation with interactive connection after the automation run (my full automation has other commands), for example:

```sh
ssh user@ip 'ls -la; bash'
```

and for some reason I don't have a complete tty like normal ssh connection (user@hostname:~$ and autocomplete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `ssh` man page says:

```
-t   Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbi-
     trary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
     very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
     options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

So you have to use

```
ssh -tt user@ip 'ls -la; bash'
```

Comment: Why does _multiple_ mean here `-ttt` and not `-tt` or `-tttt`?

Comment: Fixed it in the answer. You are right `-tt` is sufficient.